# How to push a folder cloned from one repo as a new branch to another repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm new to repos / git.

I have a project folder PF which was cloned from Repo A.
Now there's a new Repo B created.
I want to push my project folder PF as a new branch in Repo B.
And do a merge.
How do i do this?

Here's what i tried.

cloned from Repo B to a new folder

git checkout master

git pull

git checkout -b master-new-branch

Then i overwrote this entire new folder with contents (except the git specific files) of PF folder.

Tried to do a Commit and Push.

Comment: Did you make sure you staged the files before doing a commit?

Comment: Can you explain what results you got when you did this